# How to insert url of a selected article from popup in joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0

I have small plugin(which work for joomla article in admin) of joomla which has a field in xml file like :

```
<field name="url" type="modal_article" default="" label="Internal Link" 
description="" />
```

Right now it contains only articleId when I save it. 
How can I insert url of selected article like `index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=517&catid=28&Itemid=267` ?

if that is not possible how can I use **Article select** button of joomla admin editor in my custom plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert a url, change the type to url

```
<field name="url" type="url" default="" label="Internal Link" 
description="" />
```

else if you want to have a proper article select, you're using the right type but your fieldset is not importing the modal_article, hence it's rendered as text (where you end up inserting the id).  Just import modal_article from

```
administrator/components/com_content/models/fields/modal/article.php
```

like this:

```
<fieldset name="request"
    addfieldpath="/administrator/components/com_content/models/fields">

    <field name="url" type="modal_article" default="" label="Internal Link" 
         description="" />
```

this will make your current code show the modal select (you'll still need to select the right Itemid from the menu to build a proper url).

Finally, another field type you might want to consider is menuitem:

```
<field name="url" type="modal_article" default="" label="Internal Link" 
     description="" />
```

see the full docs on 
http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_form_field_types